# Can I buy a single MAC address for a computer project?

Tags: networking, mac-address, 8-bit

So, I'm currently building an 8-Bit computer, and working on getting it connected to the internet, clearly just on a simple LAN to start off, in the hope of making ARP requests and such like which would be pretty cool.
I have had a little look around and I can only find standards companies selling MAC address by the million, this wont work for me.

Does anyone know how someone can accquire a single MAC address for personal use, not making money from it, but registered non the less.

Cheers all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one idea is that Microchip sells small EEPROM memory chips preprogrammed with a MAC address. One example of this is the AT24MAC602. It also contains a unique read-only 128-bit serial number and 2Kb (256 bytes) of user-accessible serial EEPROM NVM storage.

One way to use this would be to incorporate the chip into your design. Another would be to read out the MAC with an appropriate reader and hard code the address into your project.